# Source for iframe doesn't get shown

Tags: iframe

I'm developing an app and I'd like to include its page or a part of the page on an unrelated website hosted on a different domain. To test things out, I hosted my app on localhost:3000, and a random page on localhost:80.

I used this on the random page:

```
<iframe id="my-iframe" src="http://localhost:3000"  width="300" height="500">
```

No content is shown. If I test it with ex: src="http://microsoft.com", it works well.
Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Is localhost listening on 3000? and more importantly, is this endpoint providing any data?

Comment: Yes, it is both listening and providing data. Everything works well when I type localhost:3000 in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a Rails app, this worked:

in application_controller.rb, add:

```
    before_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

    def cors_set_access_control_headers
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,    Accept,    Authorization'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
      headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'ALLOW-FROM http://publisher.dev'
    end
```

The last line is the most important. You should list the urls you want to host the iframe.

Let me know if this helps anyone.